# Gmail API Limits Per IP Address

Tags: email, gmail-api

I have an SaaS based app that is launching and I just want to make sure I understand the Gmail API limits:

IF i go here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota

I see 100000000 quota units per day

My app utilizes the API to send emails on someones behalf from their gmail account. Lets assume all emails to the Google REST API are coming from a single IP address.

My current understanding is I will be able to send 1MM emails a day total and ~2 emails a second per user, for free with out a CC.

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partly. You could send something like 1,000,000 emails per day from Gmail, but that would need to be in aggregate across many different Gmail accounts.

A user account is only allowed to send 500 emails per day, to a maximum of 100 recipients. What's more, you may find that if you are repeatedly hitting that limit, Google will simply close the account because it's being abused.

Gmail is not an SMTP mailing service - use something like SendGrid, Mandrill or Amazon SES for that.